# Centralizer of $SO(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups

Given the set $M(n,\mathbb C)$ of all complex $n\times n$ matrices, what's the centralizer of $SO(n)$ in $M(n,\mathbb C)$?

For $n=2$, the centralizer must be the matrices $A$ such that $RA=AR$ where $R$ is a rotation matrix. Since 2D rotations commute, I can see $A$ is probably a rotation matrix itself.

But let's say $n \ge 3$. Then rotations don't commute in general. Can you still find a nontrivial matrix $A$ that commutes with $R$, or is $A$ just a multiple of the identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ centralises $SO(n)$, it commutes with every $R$ of the form $R=P\left[\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}\oplus I_{n-2}\right]P^T$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix. Therefore, when $n\ge3$, $A$ must be a diagonal matrix. Consider the equality $AR=RA$ again, we can further infer that $A$ is a scalar multiple of $I_n$.

Comment: I understand you argument, but I don't follow the deduction that $A$ commuting with $P\left[\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}\oplus I_{n-2}\right]P^T$ implies $A$ is diagonal. Could you explain this step a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: @Robrt For the moment, let $P=I$ and partition $A$ as $\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}$, where $X$ is 2x2. Can you show that $AR=RA$ implies $Y,Z$ are zero matrices?

Comment: Let's see. Denote $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}=J$, then for $P=I_n$ I get $R=\pmatrix{J&0\\0&I_{n-2}}$. If I work out the matrix multiplication in $AR=RA$ I get $JY = Y$ and $ZJ=Z$ which implies $Z=Y=0$.

Comment: @Robrt Yes. Now, by choosing $P$ appropriately, you may set the 2x2 principal submatrix of $R$ corresponding to the $i$-th and $j$-th rows and columns to $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$. By the same argument, we can prove that $a_{ik}=0$ for all $k\notin\{i,j\}$. Since $i$ and $j$ are arbitrary, it follows that all off-diagonal entries of $A$ are zero.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks.